What are the limitations of Nodal Analysis?
Yea, that's the question basically. What are the limitations of Nodal Analysis?

Like, for example take the following case, we have to find out the net capacitance between A and B.
Now I want to solve this question by using nodal analysis.
I will assign B as the reference node , simply by assuming that a battery of EMF V is connected between A and B, such that the negative terminal of the battery is connected to B.
Therefore the  potential of all the points as shown by the yellow colour will be taken as 0 , and the potential of all the red points will be taken as V.

Let the potential of the two junctions shown by purple and green colour be y and x Volts respectively.
Now, we have two rules for analysis of a capacitive circuit (just like the circuit consisting of resistors) , and thar are Kirchhoff's Junction Rule and Kirchhoff's Loop Rule.
For Capacitive circuits,

Kirchhoff's Junction rule states that the incoming charge at any junction should be equal to the outgoing charge from that junction. That is , the net charge is conserved.

In Nodal Analysis for capacitive circuits, this rule is used as follows:-

As the charge remains conserved, $\sum q_i$ = 0 , if the charges are initially uncharged, and $\sum q_i$ is equal to the sum of the initial charges of the plates of the capacitors connected to the node if the capacitors have an initial charge.

Now as shown in the figure , we have three isolated systems which we can consider for the nodal analysis of the capacitive circuit , denoted by orange , light green and brown colours respectively ( I hope I haven't done a mistake here , I am new to this subject of current electricity)
As in the question it has not been mentioned that the capacitors were initially charged or not , we will assume that they were not charged initially.
Applying Charge conservation for Isolated systems 1,2 and 3:-

$\text C(V-x) + C(V-y) + CV = 0$ $\implies$ $\text V = \frac{x+y}{3}$


$\text C(y-V) + C(y-x) + Cy = 0$ $\implies$ $\text V = 3y - x$


$\text C(x-V) + C(x-y) + Cx = 0$ $\implies$ $\text V = 3x - y$

From all these equations I get the Value of V to be zero , which should not be the case. The main goal was to find the potential drop V - 0 = V from A to B , and then the total outgoing charge from the Point A , and then finding the net capacitance by the formula $C_{net} = \frac{Q}{V}$. I know there are other ways of finding the net capacitance , but I want to find the answer using this.
Can anyone help?

I suspect this will be closed as homework, but if you want to ask in the JEE physics chat room I'd be happy to go through the problem there.

The orange system is not isolated.  It's connected to the positive voltage, which means that when you connect the upper terminal to the positive voltage, charge can flow into/out of it.

Ohhh... is it also true for the brown system? @MichaelSeifert

Thanks :) by the way
